# How to remove old plastic pool deck sleeves

Tags: deck, pool, plastic, removal

How to remove old plastic pool deck sleeves. 1 1/4" hole in concrete. Sleeve is 4" deep. Broken at the top, no flange left on top.

Comment: can you post a picture?

Answer (score 1):

Select (or go buy) a cheap chisel - you don't want to do this with a nice one.

Wear safety glasses, the plastic is probably brittle with age and sun exposure.

You might want ot experiment with pouring boiling water into the hole first, to see if it makes this process easier - depending on plastic type, it may.

Set the chisel on the plastic, next to the concrete, and hammer it. Repeat as needed until the plastic sleeve is reduced to either plastic slices/shards you can remove, or possibly you may be able to remove the whole thing once you get one cut through it and can lever one of the sides inward from the hole in the concrete.

Comment: Most plastics have a very high coefficient of thermal expansion, much higher than that of concrete, so boiling water will swell the plastic sleeve inside the hole & make it more difficult to remove. I could opt for using dry ice to pack the hole, though - that'll also make the plastic much more brittle & easier to shatter.

Comment: Shucks, I forgot to bring my dry ice today.